# .is(':visible') not working?

Tags: jquery, slick.js, vimeo-player

So I'm trying to make a video slider, I'm currently using slick slider. However I want the video to pause once the slide is not in view. I've tried using the .on('before' but that broke my whole slider.

In theory the slider can have multiple video images so that's why I'm using .each()

```
$('.featured-video').each(function() {
  console.log('video function is working');
  if ($('.featured-video').is(':visible')) {
      console.log("element visible");
  } else {
      console.log("element not visible");
  }
});
```

If you need the files to the site just ask.
Why doesn't this work?
What alternatives do I have if this flat out won't work?

As a side note I'm using the Vimeo Player for the video.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery has no `:in-viewport` selector by default. Are you including the library which add's its functionality? Also note that you only check that state once when the page loads. Presumably you also need to check the element's positioning each time it slides.

Comment: My bad, I miss typed it, I've been looking at other posts, I'll edit it.

Comment: just a comment because an answer would be too much to: Did you already have a look at Intersection Observer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API ) This is a performant way to test if (and by how much) an element is visible in the viewport. There also is a polyfill for older browsers (https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)

Comment: That looks incredibly complicated but thanks, I'll have to read through it and see what I can figure out